# Add extra path manually on open_basedir

Tags: php, ffmpeg, host

I need to add an extra path manually on open_basedir, but I don't know where I can do that I guess from phpmyadmin this is possible but for an extra path for FFmpeg plugin I need to edit a fine from terminal ssh, 
this is the path I need to add: :/usr/bin/ffmpeg/:/usr/bin/ffprobe/

Thanks Developers